# EntityFramework Core, Prevent object Tracking and returning Saved object With Id

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I want localy to prevent entityFramerok to track and return my saved object with Id, the thing is I want to save this object several times in loop and change its properties, problem is when it saves for first time, object gets Id and entityframework track this object and I cant use it on second loop to create new record in database, here is a sample class:

```
 public class PolicyPackageService : Base
    {
        public PolicyPackageService() {
            ChildPackageProductServices = new HashSet<PolicyPackageService>();
            OwnedPackageProductServices = new HashSet<PolicyPackageService>();
        }
        
        public long PackageProductServiceId { get; set; }
        public long PolicyPackageId { get; set; }
        public long? ParentPolicyPackageServiceId { get; set; }
        public long? OwnerPolicyPackageServiceId { get; set; }

        public long PackageId { get; set; }
        public long? ProductId { get; set; }
        public long? ServiceId { get; set; }
        public bool? IsUnlimited { get; set; }
        public bool? IsMainProductService { get; set; }
        public bool? IsPrintableService { get; set; }
        public bool? HasFreeChoice { get; set; }
        public decimal BlockedAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal SpentAmount { get; set; }
        public bool? IsFreeService { get; set; }
        public bool? IsQuantitativeService { get; set; }
        public int? ClaimMaxCount { get; set; }
        public int? RefundedDaysCount { get; set; }

        public virtual User.User CreateUser { get; set; }
        public virtual User.User LastModifiedUser { get; set; }
        public virtual PackageProductService PackageProductService { get; set; }
        public virtual PolicyPackageService ParentPolicyPackageService { get; set; }
        public virtual PolicyPackageService OwnerPolicyPackageService { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PolicyPackageService> ChildPackageProductServices { get; private set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PolicyPackageService> OwnedPackageProductServices { get; private set; }

        public virtual PolicyPackage PolicyPackage { get; set; }
        public virtual Package Package { get; set; }
        public virtual Product.Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Catalogue.LimitType LimitType { get; set; }
        public virtual Catalogue.Service Service { get; set; }
        public virtual PremiumAmountType PremiumAmountType { get; set; }
        public virtual Person.Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual Catalogue.CoverageZone CoverageZone { get; set; }
    }
```

class is much more properties, I removed many of them, as a child objects it has its on type and they also get Ids when I save it

I used another new object for it, but it has way too much properties and objects inside it, and coping all this data affects too much on performance,
I also tried entityFramework Detach method, but It gets Ids anyways

Comment: Why won't you create and fill your object every time anew?

Comment: Can you show the loop that save the entity?

Comment: You have to create a new object instead of trying to save the current object as a new record. Entity framework tracks the changes of the object and will try to update your existing record. To avoid this you can try to make a clone or shallowcopy or something similar to make a 'new' object out of it to save as a new record.

Comment: @AgentFire that will work, but will be slow, Object is Too big and complicated to create and copy all the properties

Answer (score 1):

When a object is added in the context, that create a entity that track the object. When a object is re-added in the context, that remove the precedent entity and create a new entity that track the object.

This code insert two entities in the DB from one object :

```cs
using (var context = new DemoContext())
{
    var foo = new Foo { Label = "First" };
    context.Add(foo);
    context.SaveChanges();

    foo.Id = 0;
    foo.Label = "Second";
    context.Add(foo);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you see, the entity need to be saved in db before to be removed. With this technique, it isn't possible to bulk the insert... not sure that will help to improve performance.